# bert-base-uncased: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to see embeddings for the input text I give to the model, and then feed it to the rest of the BERT. To do so, I partitioned the model into two sequential models, but I must have done it wrong because rest_of_bert model raises TypeError. Original model does not raise any error with the input_ids as input processed with text_to_input function.

Input[0]:

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
cls_token_id = tokenizer.cls_token_id
sep_token_id = tokenizer.sep_token_id
pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id

model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True)
model.eval()
```

Output[0]:

```py
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing BertModel: ['cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
BertModel(
  (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
    (word_embeddings): Embedding(30522, 768, padding_idx=0)
    (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
    (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
    (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  )
  (encoder): BertEncoder(
    (layer): ModuleList(
      (0): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (1): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (2): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (3): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (4): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (5): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (6): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (7): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (8): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (9): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (10): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (11): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (pooler): BertPooler(
    (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (activation): Tanh()
  )
)
```

Input[1]:

```py
def text_to_input(text):
  x = tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=False) # returns python list
  x = [cls_token_id] + x + [sep_token_id]
  token_count = len(x)
  pad_count = 512 - token_count
  x = x + [pad_token_id for i in range(pad_count)]
  return torch.tensor([x])

extract_embeddings = torch.nn.Sequential(list(model.children())[0])
rest_of_bert = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[1:])

input_ids = text_to_input('A sentence.')
x_embedding = extract_embeddings(input_ids)
output = rest_of_bert(x_embedding)
```

Output[1]:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d371d8a2fb3c> in <module>()
     12 input_ids = text_to_input('A sentence.')
     13 x_embedding = extract_embeddings(input_ids)
---> 14 output = rest_of_bert(x_embedding)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py in __getitem__(self, k)
    220             return inner_dict[k]
    221         else:
--> 222             return self.to_tuple()[k]
    223 
    224     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `BertLayer` returns a tuple that contains at least one tensor (depending on what output you requested). The first element of the tuple is the tensor you want to feed to the next BertLayer.

A more huggingface-like approach would be calling the model with [output_hidden_states](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel.forward.output_hidden_states):

```py
o = model(input_ids, output_hidden_states=True)
print(len(o.hidden_states))
```

Output:

```
13
```

The first tensor of the hidden_states tuple is the output of your `extract_embeddings` object (token embeddings). The other 12 tensors are the contextualized embeddings that are the output of each `BertLayer`.

You should, by the way, provide an attention mask, because otherwise, your padding tokens will affect your output. The tokenizer is able to do that for you and you can replace your whole `text_to_input` method with:

```py
tokenizer('A sentence.', return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', max_length=512)
```